# Matlab: Make NxN matrix from a N^2x3 csv

Tags: matlab, csv, matrix

I have a similarity matrix in the form of a csv file with three columns. The first two columns contain the ids of elements being compared and the third column contains the similarity score:

```
5   5   1
5   4   0.873012914
5   3   0.817896388
5   2   0.801996649
5   1   0.765290669
5   10  0.770606211
5   39  0.683117659
...
```

I'd like to transform this into an NxN matrix which looks like this:

```
    5             4         ...
5   1             0.873013
4   0.873013      1
3   0.817896388   ...
2   0.801996649 
1   0.765290669 
...
```

I can do this in python (using DictWriter) but I am trying to learn matlab and I get the sense there is a way to do this in matlab which might be easier. How would one do this in matlab (either with a script or within the command line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `csvread` to read in the file (you should use `dlmread` instead if it's actually tab-delimited like you've shown) and then you can use `sub2ind` to convert the first two columns into linear indices and then use these to place the third column into the requested matrix.

```
M = csvread('filename.csv');

% Make a matrix of all zeros to start
output = zeros(max(M(:,1)));

% Fill in the pairings
output(sub2ind(size(output), M(:,1), M(:,2))) = M(:,3);
```

And if you want the output in the *exact* format (with the 5's in the top left) you've shown, you'll want to flip it around a bit

```
output = flipud(fliplr(output));
```

Another option would be to use `sparse` to populate the matrix from the first two columns.

```
M = csvread('filename.csv');
output = full(sparse(M(:,1), M(:,2), M(:,3)));
```

**Update**

Since you don't have *all* ID values between 1 and 65 and you want to include the IDs in the first row and first column, you'll want to do something like the following.

```
% Determine the unique IDs and get the rows and columns for each ID in
% the first two columns
[unique_ids, ~, rows] = unique(M(:,1));
[~, ~, cols] = unique(M(:,2)); 

% Initialize the output matrix
output = zeros(numel(unique_ids) + 1);

% Create the row and column labels of IDs
output(2:end,1) = unique_ids;
output(1,2:end) = unique_ids;

% Fill in the rest
output(sub2ind(size(output), rows + 1, cols + 1)) = M(:,3);
```

Comment: The second way (using sparse) seems to populate the entire matrix with just zeroes

Comment: @Dider Hmm are you sure that you have copied it exactly? Make sure that you've also loaded `M` from the csv file again prior to calling it.

Comment: Ok now there's an issue with the first method, I get the following error when trying to run `output(sub2ind(size(output), M(:,1), M(:,2))) = M(:,3);`:
`Error using sub2ind (line 43) Out of range subscript.`

Comment: @Dider Are you sure that you have a row for every possible combination of the first two columns? If you can't guarantee that, the second approach is going to be more reliable

Comment: The id numbers are not sequential, there are gaps. E.g 
2
1
10
39
38
40
37
Otherwise, each id number is paired with every other id number. The second method works, but I also need the labels (the ids) as the first column and first row

Comment: @Dider If you can provide a link to the file I can look into what the issue is. The order shouldn't matter as long as you have every ID between 1 and `N`

Comment: @Dider Yea so you didn't have all values between 1 and 65 as IDs. I've updated the first one to cope with this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133173/discussion-between-dider-and-suever).